# "find: missing argument to `-exec'" when using "-exec rm -f {}\"

Tags: command-line, find

I run this command:

```
~/shell_temp$ find . -type f -name "IMAG1806.jpg" -exec rm -f {}\
```

i got output below:

```
> IMAG1806.jpg

Error:
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

what is exact command for find any file from current directory and remove with `-exec`?

Comment: Can't you just to `rm "IMAG1806.jpg"`? It's in the same directory, so you know what it's called.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - would assume the OP is doing a "dry run". I would consider using a -i with rm just in case your find "finds" more files then intended or at least running without the -exec and reviewing the file list

Comment: @Zacharee1: The find command will delete all files called with this name in the current directory and all of its subdirectories (at any depth).

Comment: Or instead of using `-exec rm` just use `-delete` directly.

Answer (score 31):

You missed the a `;` at the end (and a space too between `{}` and `;`). The correct command is:

```
find . -type f -name "IMAG1806.jpg" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

`;` indicates the end of `-exec` predicate of `find`.

Also note that we have used `\;` i.e. `\` in front of `;` to escape the interpretation of `;` by shell, otherwise shell will treat `;` as end of the whole `find` command and `find` will throw the same error. You can also use `';'` instead of `\;`.

You were using `\` at the end, this indicates your shell will continue to take input via `PS2` (indicated by `>`), you typed `IMAG1806.jpg` again, so the whole command becomes:

```
find . -type f -name "IMAG1806.jpg" -exec rm -f {}IMAG1806.jpg
```

As you can see this is not a valid command at all with `IMAG1806.jpg` at the end, no closing of `-exec` predicate and without a space between `{}` and `\;`.

Comment: "You missed the a `;` at the end " Thanks for this, spent 10 minutes troubleshooting before I realized I had accidentally typed `:` instead of `;`, on these modern HD screens its easy to miss...

Answer (score 9):

You can simply

```
find . -type f -name 'IMAGE1806.jpg' -delete
```

From the man page:

```
Delete files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed,
an  error message is issued.  If -delete fails, find's exit sta‐
tus will be nonzero (when it eventually exits).  Use of  -delete
automatically turns on the -depth option.
```